# “react must be in scope” error while creating React project

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, npx

I am new to React.JS, I created a new project using react command
`npx create-react-app` but after creating the project I received an error:

> `'react' must be in scope when using jsx react/react-in-jsx-scope`

Comment: Have you imported react in your jsx file? ```import React from 'react'```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Version > React 17.

This is an ESLint rule that can be disabled in your `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json` file. In older versions of React each file had to have `import React from "react"` as an import, however in newer versions of React (since React 17) this is no longer required. This rule made sure (in older versions) that it was imported so there'd be no unseen errors, however now you clearly still have this rule enabled somehow.

Try adding `"react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,` under the `rules` section of your `.eslintrc`/`.eslintrc.json` file.

Version < React 17.

You need to add `import React from "react"` to the top of your file.